# SQLCMD is showing tables not in pretty way

Tags: sql-server, powershell, terminal, sqlcmd

I want to have access from time to time to my SQL Server database from the command line or linux terminal, but I encountered problem with reading results. It seems that tables are to wide what makes it unreadable. It there a way to define columns width?

[image]

Comment: This might be better moved to https://dba.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1):

In a command prompt, you can make the window buffer wider and then the system can make use of that width:
[image]

You access the above by right-clicking within the command prompt's title bar and choosing "Properties".

And here's a prompt where I ran the same query twice, adjusting the width (as above) between the two:

[image]

I would imagine that there are similar settings available in powershell (should be exactly the same, so far as I'm aware) and in Linux terminal windows also.

The alternative would be to be more selective in your queries (fewer columns) and use of `SUBSTRING` to limit the width of your selections, such that they fit within 80 columns (default command prompt width)